# setuid(0) gives EPERM on Mac OS X 10.9

Tags: macos, launchd, setuid

when executing this:

```
err = setuid(0);
if (err < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "return value: %d \n", err);
    fprintf(stderr, "error code: %d \n", errno);
 }
```

I am getting this output:

```
return value: -1 
error code: 1
```

Error code 1 implies an EPERM error. Any ideas as to how should I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot `setuid()` to root from a non-root user.

If you want to run your application as root, use [Authorization Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Reference/authorization_ref/Reference/reference.html), or `sudo` if it's a command-line tool.

Comment: It was working fine on less than 10.9, is there any specific changes in 10.9 that is restricting it from this.

Answer (score 0):

[SETUID(2) Man Pages](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/setuid.2.html)

> If the user is not the super user, or the uid specified is not the
>   real, effective ID, or saved ID,these functions return -1.

`setuid(0);` will work only from root(SU) user.

error code: 1

```
#define EPERM       1       /* Operation not permitted */
```